# Is this WCF serialization approach reasonable?

Tags: wcf, serialization, deserialization

I'm looking at using WCF to do client/server, UI/database layers, the thought being that I would use a WCF service to read a DataRow, populate the properties of a class and then return that to the UI client (this is Windows end-to-end).

I started with a class in a DLL, and shared the DLL between the UI and the server. The server reads the DataRow, and the class knows how to populate itself from a DataRow. The class has public properties with private backing variables but when populating from the DataRow, the class writes direct to the backing variables. The instance of the class is then passed back to the UI.

The UI deserializes the class. The class has public properties, and the setters all do the INotifyPropertyChanged stuff to support binding. So far, no normal.

I started with [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes, but noticed that when an instance of my object gets de-serialized at the UI, it calls the public property setters of an instance of the class - which in turn fires a 'has changed' event for each property.

To get around that, I read that I could use IXmlSerializer. So I removed the attributes, and supported the IXmlSerializer interface, using the ReadXml() method to write direct to the backing variables behind the public properties.

This all works fine (with the exception of now having to have a parameterless constructor), but is it reasonable ? Is this how things are supposed to work ?

Should I not have a shared class which, from the UI, knows about INotifyPropertyChanged and which, from the server end, knows how to construct itself from a DataRow. Should I put all that logic somewhere else, and define the class using XSD ?

The trouble is that I can probably solve the problems I come across (like how to deserialize nullable types) but I'm not really certain that there isn't a better way. I have no foreseeable need to support anything other than Windows to Windows WCF communication, so I don't actually care what the XML looks like (or whether it exists at all).

Pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to maintain a contract on the server side (which will be serializable via [DataContract], [DataMember]) and an entity on the client side. Any given service method will return the contract, but you wouldn't call the service directly. Instead, put a proxy in the middle. The proxy will call the service method, convert from contract to entity, and then return the entity.

This way, your front end is only concerned with its entity (since it only talks to the proxy - never directly to the service) and doesn't have to worry about the contract at all. And you don't have to do your own funky serialization stuff :)